# how local html page should fit the device screen?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, scaling

hello I convert word file in to html and put in asset folder and show in android web-view but it's not fit in web-view how to fit in all mobile screen?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

to the `<head>` section of your HTML.